# How to build a PDF repository in WordPress

Tags: page-template, pdf

I'm seeking advice on the best way to construct a PDF repository. Basically, there will be an uploader in the administrator section and in the front end. The user should be allowed to add tags to the files.

So I guess I need:

- Front-end uploader
- Backend-uploader
- Custom-post type?
- Security to check the PDF files and not just upload anything.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, the support for tagging media is pretty disappointing. You can add tags or categories to the attachment post type, but you'll find the UI is unacceptably bad (it's a text box where you enter terms separated by commas). There's a plugin [Media Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-tags/) that is decent though, so you might look into that.

GravityForms is nice for front-end uploading, but make sure you're thinking through security if you have a front-end upload system.

Alternatively, you might be able to create a special role that only has access to upload and manage their own media items. You can write your own custom role or use something like Members or User Role Editor to do that.

Once you've setup all that, it's just a matter of building out some nice taxonomy and attachment archive pages.

Comment: I should add that as of WordPress 3.5 you can register a taxonomy for the attachment post type and it works beautifully. You can even take advantage of the new `show_admin_column` argument on register post type. It's great and completely removes the need for the Media Tags plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this form it think it will help you get what you need done.
http://www.gravityforms.com/